# fullpage.js and wordpress integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fullpage.js

I have a site:

URL: http://362.a07.myftpupload.com/
Password: aynhoe_park

I'm trying to make the scroll force to go from section to section instead of a normal page scroll.. I have tried setting in the fullpage.js (http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) and I can't seem to get it to recognise it.

Can anyone have a look and help me get this working? As I can't seem to see why I can't get the page to scroll from one section to another like the fullpage.js site.

Comment: Just to let you know, there are [wordpress themes](https://goo.gl/HuFudq) using fullpage.js nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the solution. The code I was using was wrong. It ended up being this jQuery library I needed to use : https://github.com/guins/jQuery.scrollSections

Which was

`<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('section.section').scrollSections();
    });
</script>`

With the accompanying js files.

Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with a misplaced `,`.

This is your code currently

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.fullpage({
            anchors: ['home','aboutus','ourblog','yourhost','thecollection','thehouse','exclusivehire',]
            menu: '.nav',
            scrollOverflow: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

The anchors has an extra `,` in the `[]` but there isn't one after to say there are more elements coming.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.fullpage({
            anchors: ['home','aboutus','ourblog','yourhost','thecollection','thehouse','exclusivehire'],
            menu: '.nav',
            scrollOverflow: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

**jQuery Problem**

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#fullpage').fullpage();
        jQuery.fn.fullpage({
            anchors: ['home','aboutus','ourblog','yourhost','thecollection','thehouse','exclusivehire'],
            menu: '.nav',
            scrollOverflow: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do anything :( It still just scrolling like it does normally.. Ideally I need it to scroll one entire section at a time when you scroll down (if that makes sense).

Comment: If you have another look at the site you will see the code is now there, but not doing anything :(

Comment: if you look at your console log, you get 2 errors relating to jQuery. One is an `undefined is not a function` for your opening tag and the other is an `unexpected identifier` which is probably due to the jQuery being broken. Try the above amendment that i have made.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it broke all the jQuery (the last set of code you put up :( ) Its a bit odd really. I have put in the code as you gave it above but I changed out the jQuery for $ and its reduced the jQuery errors to 1 now. Its just not identified as a function.. which is odd.

Comment: I tried using some other code to see if it made any difference (you will see i've added slimscroll.min.js and a couple of extra lines of code) but its still the same problem, Its saying that the function i'm calling.. isn't a function.. which is weird.

Comment: I used this as an example, but I still can't see what i'm doing wrong?
http://wordpress-123465.sae1.nitrousbox.com/azal/

Comment: Ok, no longer getting any errors, but still not getting the page to scroll at all :( really don't get it.